# Invalid cname error while adding a cname

Tags: dns, cname

I am getting invalid cname error while adding     2-01-3d52-0001.cdx.cedexis.net on dynect.net. Any idea why i am getting this error? What is wrong in cname?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your DNS server checks the validity of domain names according to an outdated RFC:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names

The old RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952 cited there says:

> The first
> character must be an alpha character.

While the current one https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123 says:

> 2.1  Host Names and Numbers
>
> ```
>   The syntax of a legal Internet host name was specified in RFC-952
>   [DNS:4].  One aspect of host name syntax is hereby changed: the
>   restriction on the first character is relaxed to allow either a
>   letter or a digit.  Host software MUST support this more liberal
>   syntax.
> ```